# REST GET API with optional parameters - design and implementation

Tags: java, api, rest, get

Had a REST end-point in my virtual library to list all the books we have there:

```
@GetMapping(path = "/books")
public List<Book> getBooks() {
    return bookService.findAllBooks();
}
```

They said: "Sometimes we want to filter that list by book author while requesting from UI"

Now it's:

```
  @GetMapping(path = "/books")
  public List<Book> getBooks(
      @RequestParam(value = "author", required = false) String author) {
    if (isEmpty(author)) {
      return bookService.findAllBooks();
    } else {
      return bookService.findBooksByAuthor(bookName);
    }
  }
```

Now they say: "Now we want to be able to filter all books sometimes by year as well"

So I thought... is it going to become like:

```
  @GetMapping(path = "/books")
  public List<Book> getBooks(
      @RequestParam(value = "author", required = false) String author,
      @RequestParam(value = "year", required = false) String year) {
    if (isNotEmpty(author)) {
      return bookService.findBooksByAuthor(author);
    } else if (isNotEmpty(year)) {
      return bookService.findBooksByYear(year);
    } else {
      return bookService.findAllBooks();
    }
  }
```

if later they ask for more optional params - should I split this API onto separate end-points or invent some sophisticated and intelligent search?
How would you go here?

Comment: Check out this site: https://blog.tratif.com/2017/11/23/effective-restful-search-api-in-spring/ It provides a great tutorial for the exact problem you're facing

Comment: thx @BankBuilder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those, who interested - i decided not to make it too cool like solutions for java conferences.
So the solution was:

1. accept parameters as @RequestParam values in one end-point
2. build Map of those parameters (to make them similar to json)
3. create search "probe" representing entity with partial parameters
   populated
4. use org.springframework.data.domain.Example e.g.

   `Example<Book> bookExample = Example.of(probe, ExampleMatcher.matchingAll())`
5. use `org.springframework.data.repository.query.QueryByExampleExecutor#findAll(org.springframework.data.domain.Example<S>)` e.g. `bookRepository.findAll(bookExample)`

to find only those entities which match incoming parameters

BINGO.